# How to select between dates Spring data MongoDB using @Query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I'm using Spring data with MongoDB and i need to find between actual day and 7 days ahead.

I have create repsoitories with @Query annotation and don't like to user Criteria class.

Do you have some idea how to user between with @Query?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can try below query.

Using @Query annotation

```
@Query(value = "{'date':{ $lt: ?0, $gt: ?1}}")
List<SomeClass> findByDateBetween(Instant from, Instant to);
```

Or

Using repository supported keywords

```
List<SomeClass> findByDateBetween(Instant from, Instant to);
```

Comment: the @Query solution solves my problem, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Is there a way to have this work while also including additional criteria to filter on?

Answer (score 0):

You can try thquery.

```
@Query(value = "{'champsDate':{ $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1}}")
List<entity> findByChampsDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
```