# Issue while fetching data between dates using Java Spring Boot MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am getting an error while trying to fetch data between a date range. I understand there is an issue in the code as the fields in the parameter do not exist. All I need is to fetch the data between a date range passed through the API.

**Error**

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2021-01-24T20:59:53.074+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Missing URI template variable 'stexpdate' for method parameter of type String\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver.java:101)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:226)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:114)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)\r\n",
    "message": "Missing URI template variable 'stexpdate' for method parameter of type String",
    "path": "/findBetDates/12-01-2020/12-02-2020"
}
```

**Controller Code**

```java
@GetMapping("/findBetDates/{expdate}/{expdate}")
public List<mydataExp> getByExpdateBetw(@PathVariable String stexpdate, @PathVariable String edexpdate) {
    return expenseRepository.findExpDateBetw(stexpdate, edexpdate);
}
```

**Repository Code**

```java
public interface ExpenseRepository extends MongoRepository<mydataExp, Integer> 
{
    @Query("{'expdate' : { $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1 } }")   
    List<mydataExp> findExpDateBetw(String stexpdate, String edexpdate);
}
```

**Model**

```java
@Document(collection = "mydataExp")
public class mydataExp {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String expdate;
    private String exptype;
    private int expamt;
}
```

I am a beginner to Java and Spring Boot. Please help. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: You have a bad mapping in your GetMapping annotation try to name variables the same as in your method `@GetMapping("/findBetDates/{stexpdate}/{edexpdate}")`

Explanation of your mistake is in the error response - `Missing URI template variable 'stexpdate' for method parameter of type String`. Spring cannot map your template in annotation to assigned method arguments.

Comment: Yeah i got that thanks.. but how do i pass a date range to the same date(expdate in the table). i want to fetch data with dates between two different dates. pLease

Comment: Try to use `Instant` or `Date` objects -> helpful will be this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698985/how-to-select-between-dates-spring-data-mongodb-using-query/43699233